# Use web service in WinCE5

Tags: c#

I write a program in WINCE5(c# 2.0) and want to interaction with my web service also written in C#2.0.

But when I use WSDL utility to generate a Service.cs and refer to it in my CE project as usual. I found I can not pass compile due to:

```
The type or namespace name 'AsyncCompletedEventArgs' does not exist in the namespace     'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

As you may know, there're some differents in .NET Compact framework. But who can kindly tell me how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229663.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I add reference in VS IDE and expose it using Object Browser ,not using wsdl to generate proxy. That looks okay. Thank you, perfect answer.